# How to set up dependency properties with Xamarin.Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin, nsobject, xamarin.mac

I have the following object with a couple of properties:

```
public class Test : NSObject
{
    [Export("formattedFoo")]
    public string FormattedFoo { get { return string.Format("Test {0}", Foo); } }

    [Export("foo")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

In Interface Builder, I have a text field bound to `foo` and a label bound to `formattedFoo`. Whenever the user types text into the text field, the `Foo` property is updated, as intended. However, the label does not get updated.

I suspect there is something I need to implement in order to communicate the dependency relationship between `foo` and `formattedFoo` to Cocoa, but I am not sure what.

Before anyone jumps in suggesting I use a formatting expression in IB, that's not really an option as the above is a vastly oversimplified example of the real-life scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, here are the relevant resources:

- [From Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE)
- [From Xamarin (Miguel)](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2010/Dec-07.html)

The code needs to be extended with the following method:

```
[Export("keyPathsForValuesAffectingFormattedFoo")]
public static NSSet GetDependenciesForFormattedFoo()
{
     return new NSSet("foo");
}
```

Basically, you have to have a `public static` method that has its name starting with "keyPathsForValuesAffecting" and ending with the name of the property that has dependencies.